# TeX Live 2022 PPA on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: texlive

Currently only 2021 version of TeX Live is available in Ubuntu 22.04 repositories. (Kinetic already has 2022 version however.) Is there a ppa with 2022 version of TeX Live that one could use without upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 or installing TeX Live "by hand?"

Comment: PPA is not Ubuntu it is something the maker of the app maintains. So you would need to check with them.

Comment: I also would like if the default apt version of TeX Live would update. Current Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version is `2019.20200218-1`. That is really old and installing it by hand is a pita.

Comment: If you want the latest version of TeXLive, follow the manual steps in [https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)

Comment: It helps if you have a fast internet connection for download (>=900Mbps) and at least 7.5 GB of free disk space. The result is (edited for brevity): `latex --version`

`pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
...
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04`